# Facebook SDK Share button not showing up

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, share

So, I'm trying to implement the plugin for share on fb button but it's not showing up. The button is there but it automatically has a class that hides it that comes from facebook SDK not me and I don't know how to take it out.

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                        appId      : '1633098193720369',
                        cookie     : true,
                        xfbml      : true,
                        version    : 'v13.0',
                    });
    
                    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                        statusChangeCallback(response);
                    });
                };
    
                (function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    
                function statusChangeCallback(response) {
                    if(response.status === 'connected') {
                        console.log('Logged in and anthenticated');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not authenticated');
                    }
                }
    
                function checkLoginState() {
                    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                        statusChangeCallback(response);
                    });
                }

                window.logout = function () {
                    FB.logout(function () {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    });
                };
            });
        </script>
        <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<div id="#share-on-fb"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then I add the fb button from a javascript file along with the content I want to show:

```
$('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="https://encuentrame.org.xelar.tech/static/images/' + post.foto + '" />');
let shareOnFb = $('#share-on-fb');
shareOnFb.append('<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="' + url + '" data-layout="button" data-size="small"></div>');
```

Take a look at the page, the button div is there but height is 0 automatically
https://imgur.com/gallery/pGh46er

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook parses all tags when the page loads. If you add tags afterwards you have to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/ to reparse the specific tag or the whole page.

Also be aware that dynamically setting og:image in javascript will not work. Facebook will scrape the URL and look for og:image. So what the og:image is when the user clicks the share button doesn't matter.

Comment: The thing was that nothing can be added dynamically, the html file with the plugin must be static. I'm using Flask and Jinja and every .html file inherits from a base file. I had to remove that and remove the .js file with AJAX as well. The good thing is that it's just one endpoint and not the whole application. Anyway, you made me realize about all that, thanks!